# Skylight in bathroom a bad idea?

Tags: skylight

I'm contemplating putting a skylight in a bathroom that would otherwise get little natural light. I've received some mixed advice with one person telling me the shower condensation will cause a long term problem while another says it will be fine.

Is that a good reason to avoid a bathroom skylight?

Comment: i have a skylight in my bathroom ... no problems ... house built 1997

Comment: modern skylights are all multi-layer high efficiency glass with good insulation, there shouldn't be a large thermal differential between the inside plate and the room temp. If your bathroom is vented, i can't see anything other than a long steam bath during a blizzard causing any condensation.

Answer (score 1):

I just bought a house and one of the bathrooms has a skylight. I have not noticed any issues taking a bath. As dandavis mentioned, I see condensation because one of my kids thinks the shower is a sauna. Pretty normal otherwise. And I have to say that during the day, even when overcast, it looks pretty bright in that bathroom. A cool feature.

Answer (score 0):

I not only have skylights in my bathroom, I have one in the shower. Granted, it's a large shower (4x6 feet) and the skylight sits over a thrust out, sort of like a shelf, so the skylight itself is about 5 feet away horizontally and 5 feet higher than the shower fixtures. It was installed in 1996 and I've had no problem. I do suggest that if it is wood trim that you use a marine based varnish or stain. The wood does get a little faded and worn after about 6-7 years, probably from a combination of condensation and UV, so I sand it down and restain it. I am careful about running the exhaust fan.